# How Can Create POP-UP menu in cocos2d-X for IOS

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new in cocos2d-X. Please help me to create a pop-up menu in cocos2d-x .. How can create a subview and add that view to the existing scene.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd subclass `cocos2d::Layer` or `cocos2d::LayerColor`.

When you need the pop-up menu, add it as a child to the current layer (or where ever makes sense in your game) making sure to set the `zOrder` to something higher than the current layer so it shows up on top.

You may hear these referred to as `HUD Layers`

Here is someone that creates a simple HUD Layer: http://cocos2dx.wordpress.com/category/cocos2dx/